# Always clean a dependent recipe

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe

We have a recipe `A` that depends on another recipe `B`. Whenever we redo recipe `B` using, for example, `bitbake -c cleanall B` and `bitbake core-image-minimal`, yocto correctly builds `B` and then tries to build `A`. However, recipe `A` (which we did not write) has some issues when you try to call the individual steps (i.e. `configure`, `compile`, e.t.c.) without cleaning first. Is there a way instruct bitbake to automatically clean recipe `A` whenever recipe `B` is cleaned (or rebuilt)?

Edit: To clarify, there are actually a couple of recipes that fail. For example, for [fsbl](https://github.com/Xilinx/meta-xilinx-tools/blob/rel-v2020.2/recipes-bsp/fsbl/fsbl_git.bb) the error is

```
| ERROR: Execution of '[...]/yocto/build/tmp/work/zcu216_zynqmp-poky-linux/fsbl/2020.2+gitAUTOINC+08b9f4304d-r0/temp/run.do_configure.581607' failed with exit code 1:
| MISC_ARG is  -yamlconf [...]/yocto/build/tmp/work/zcu216_zynqmp-poky-linux/fsbl/2020.2+gitAUTOINC+08b9f4304d-r0/fsbl.yaml -lib libmetal
| APP_ARG is  -app "Zynq MP FSBL"
| Using xsct from: /opt/Xilinx/Vitis/2020.2/bin/xsct
| cmd is: xsct -sdx -nodisp [...]/yocto/build/tmp/work/zcu216_zynqmp-poky-linux/fsbl/2020.2+gitAUTOINC+08b9f4304d-r0/app.tcl -ws [...]/yocto/build/tmp/work/zcu216_zynqmp-poky-linux/fsbl/2020.2+gitAUTOINC+08b9f4304d-r0/build -pname fsbl -rp [...]/yocto/build/tmp/work/zcu216_zynqmp-poky-linux/fsbl/2020.2+gitAUTOINC+08b9f4304d-r0/git -processor psu_cortexa53_0 -hdf [...]/yocto/build/tmp/deploy/images/zcu216-zynqmp/Xilinx-zcu216-zynqmp.xsa -arch 64  -app "Zynq MP FSBL"  -yamlconf [...]/yocto/build/tmp/work/zcu216_zynqmp-poky-linux/fsbl/2020.2+gitAUTOINC+08b9f4304d-r0/fsbl.yaml -lib libmetal
| INFO: [Hsi 55-2053] elapsed time for repository (/opt/Xilinx/Vitis/2020.2/data/embeddedsw) loading 0 seconds
| INFO: Update hw fsbl_plat project
| Loading the sw platform from [...]/yocto/build/tmp/work/zcu216_zynqmp-poky-linux/fsbl/2020.2+gitAUTOINC+08b9f4304d-r0/build/fsbl_plat/platform.spr
| Reading the platform  : "fsbl_plat"
| Opening the hardware design, this may take few seconds.
| Failed to generate bsp for application zynqmp_fsbl
|     while executing
| "builtin_platform -addbootdomains "
|     (procedure "platform" line 393)
|     invoked from within
| "platform create -name $params(hwpname) -hw $params(hdf) -out $params(ws)"
|     invoked from within
| "if { $params(ws) ne "" } {
|   #Local Work Space available
|   if { $params(pname) ne "" } {
|       # hwpname/bspname is empty then default it to pname+_hwproj/b[...]"
|     (file "[...]/yocto/build/tmp/work/zcu216_zynqmp-poky-linux/fsbl/2020.2+gitAUTOINC+08b9f4304d-r0/app.tcl" line 139)
| WARNING: [...]/yocto/build/tmp/work/zcu216_zynqmp-poky-linux/fsbl/2020.2+gitAUTOINC+08b9f4304d-r0/temp/run.do_configure.581607:1 exit 1 from 'eval xsct -sdx -nodisp [...]/yocto/build/tmp/work/zcu216_zynqmp-poky-linux/fsbl/2020.2+gitAUTOINC+08b9f4304d-r0/app.tcl -ws [...]/yocto/build/tmp/work/zcu216_zynqmp-poky-linux/fsbl/2020.2+gitAUTOINC+08b9f4304d-r0/build -pname fsbl -rp [...]/yocto/build/tmp/work/zcu216_zynqmp-poky-linux/fsbl/2020.2+gitAUTOINC+08b9f4304d-r0/git -processor psu_cortexa53_0 -hdf [...]/yocto/build/tmp/deploy/images/zcu216-zynqmp/Xilinx-zcu216-zynqmp.xsa -arch 64 ${APP_ARG} ${MISC_ARG}'
```

But multiple recipes fail, some with other error messages. I believe that, when a `make` based recipe fails, the error is something like `cannot find some_directory.new` but I will add more details when I see another error. Unfortunately, the errors are not as reproducible as I would want them to be...

Comment: You did not describe kind of error you are getting, which could help in refining the answer, you could try adding `CLEANBROKEN = "1"` to recipe A which will ensure that it does not run `make clean` before re-running do_configure. That is if makefiles of B are broken somehow. Another option is use `do_taskname[cleandirs] = "dir"` syntax to delete needed directories before the task is run e.g. do_configure etc.

Comment: I have added an example error message. Is the `CLEANBROKEN = "1"` just for debugging purposes? I actually want to clean the recipes using `make clean`. Would the second option be placed in Recipe B as a `bbappend`?